# How to change Opencart 3.x default theme to support Bootstrap 5?

Tags: opencart

How to change Opencart 3.x default theme to support Bootstrap 5? There are 800+ line of codes in Checkout page. I need to develop this theme in Bootstrap 5. Or suggest any free theme to support Bootstrap 5.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

To change default theme to support BS5 - there is only one solution - to do it by rewrition the whole theme. It can takes from 2 to 5 wording days, depends on lyour skills level and knolage of BS3, 4, and 5.

Here you can read about migrations

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/

Also there is a demo site I made, OpenCard 3 default theme but using BS5, and meny other modern libraries.
https://fs3.focus.style/

Comment: Thank you. Can you please share the Checkout view page that will be more helpful for me? Or can you share a free template with Bootstrap 5 framework.